LLVM Phi Node throwing errors even though the types are the same
I'm new to LLVM and I've been trying to create my own compiler for a pet language following the kaleidoscope tutorials. Had a hurdle when trying to create PHI Nodes even though i followed exactly the code in the tutorial to generate a phi node.
for context ; what I'm trying to do is generate an if/else statement with a single expression inside. The parses looks fine and returns the expected types, however when it comes to generating the PHI Node and the Body of the if else itself it fails.
Here's the Output I printed to the console :
Then Value type is : double
Else Value type is : double
Then BB type is : label
Else BB type is : label
Phi Node type is : double
Function IR is :
define double @func(double %a) {
entry:
  %cmptmp = fcmp ueq double %a, 2.000000e+00
  br i1 %cmptmp, label %then, label %else

then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %addtmp = fadd double %a, 1.000000e+00
  br label %ifcont

else:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %subtmp = fsub double %a, 2.000000e+00
  br label %ifcont

ifcont:                                           ; preds = %else, %then
  %iftmp = phi double [ %addtmp, %then ], [ %subtmp, %else ]
  ret double %iftmp
}

Function Finally is :define double @0() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call double @func(double 2.000000e+00)
  ret double %calltmp
}
error : Operand is null
  %iftmp = phi double [ %addtmp, %then ], [ %subtmp, %else ]

This Code is generated for the following syntax of my own language :
def func(a)
{
    if a==2 ; a+1 else a-2
}
func(2)

And here's the Code Snippet for my If/Else Body Code Generator :
llvm::Value* IfExpr::codegen()
{
    Value* CondV = Cond->codegen();
    auto Builder = Compiler::getInstance().getBuilder();
    auto TheContext = Compiler::getInstance().getContext();
    if (!CondV)
        return nullptr;
    Function* TheFunction = Builder->GetInsertBlock()->getParent();
    // Create blocks for the then and else cases.  Insert the 'then' block at the
    // end of the function.
    BasicBlock* ThenBB =
        BasicBlock::Create(*TheContext, "then", TheFunction);
    BasicBlock* ElseBB = BasicBlock::Create(*TheContext, "else");
    BasicBlock* MergeBB = BasicBlock::Create(*TheContext, "ifcont");

    Builder->CreateCondBr(CondV, ThenBB, ElseBB);
    // Emit then value.
    Builder->SetInsertPoint(ThenBB);

    Value* ThenV = Then->codegen();
    if (!ThenV)
        return nullptr;
    
    Builder->CreateBr(MergeBB);
    // Codegen of 'Then' can change the current block, update ThenBB for the PHI.
    ThenBB = Builder->GetInsertBlock();
    // Emit else block.
    TheFunction->insert(TheFunction->end(), ElseBB);
    Builder->SetInsertPoint(ElseBB);

    Value* ElseV = Else->codegen();
    if (!ElseV)
        return nullptr;
    Builder->CreateBr(MergeBB);
    // codegen of 'Else' can change the current block, update ElseBB for the PHI.
    ElseBB = Builder->GetInsertBlock();

    // Emit merge block.
    TheFunction->insert(TheFunction->end(), MergeBB);
    Builder->SetInsertPoint(MergeBB);
    PHINode* PN =
        Builder->CreatePHI(Type::getDoubleTy(*TheContext), 2, "iftmp");

    errs() << "Then Value type is : ";
    ThenV->getType()->print(errs());
    errs() << "Else Value type is : ";
    ElseV->getType()->print(errs()); 

    errs() << "Then BB type is : ";
    ThenBB->getType()->print(errs());
    errs() << "Else BB type is : ";
    ElseBB->getType()->print(errs());
    errs() << "Phi Node type is : ";
    PN->getType()->print(errs());

    PN->addIncoming(ThenV, ThenBB);
    PN->addIncoming(ElseV, ElseBB);
    
    if (!PN) {
        std::cout << "Failed to generate Phi Node";
        return nullptr;
    }
    return PN;
}

Feel Free to shout out any blatant bad practices you see I'm new to C++ and LLVM so any feedback I can get is a plus! I'm also very lost in the debugging of LLVM so if anyone has tips please let me know. I'm running my code in Visual Studio 2017 and linking/adding dependencies through the project settings.

The two questions I have are a) are you using an LLVM with assertions enabled? Make sure you are. b) does llvm::verifyFunction() have anything to say about the finished functions?
